# Insert doesn't affect immediately on SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server

Got a really weird problem from SQL Server 2012: Can't find my data right after I inserted it.

I wrote a java test program that insert and fetch data from my table, functions here:

```
public void insert(Int ID, String data, Timestamp date) {

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        con = ds.getConnection(); // using Datasource to get connection
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PrivData(ID, MyData, Create_date) VALUES(?,?,?)");

        pstmt.setInt(1, ID);
        pstmt.setString(2, data);
        pstmt.setTimestamp(3, date);

        int result = pstmt.executeUpdate();

        con.commit();

        Log4j.info("Insert result: " + result);

    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } finally {
        if (pstmt != null) {
            try {
                pstmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        }
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        }
    }
}

public MyData findData(int ID) {

    Mydata result = null;
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {

        con = ds.getConnection(); // using Datasource to get connection
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM PrivData WHERE ID=?");

        pstmt.setInt(1, ID);

        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            result = new Mydata();
            result.setID(rs.getInt("ID"));
            result.setData(rs.getString("MyData"));
            result.setDate(rs.getTimestamp("Create_date"));
        }

    } catch (SQLException se) {
        throw new RuntimeException("A database error occured. "
                + se.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        }
        if (pstmt != null) {
            try {
                pstmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        }
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then I give it a try:

```
insert(1, "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
Mydata myData = findData(1);

if(myData == null) {
    Log4j.info("Failed to get data from DB");
    System.out.println("Failed to get data from DB");
    return;
}
else {
    System.out.println(myData.getData());
}
```

When I run those code, the Insert part gave me the `[INFO ] Insert result: 1` in log. So I suppose to get my data back at `Mydata myData = findData(1);` but NO: It got caught by `if(myData == null)`. Which mean that data does not exist in DB.

BUT if I search my DB after this code is done, that data do inserted into table and I will be able to get them using same code and ID(with `insert()` is commented). So I think there is SOMETHING that stalled my `INSERT` at first run but I'm not sure which part caused that...

Can anyone tell me how to solve this weird problem?

---

### -----Update-----

@Ben Thul
Well, that `Mydata` is nothing complicated.

```
Class Mydata {
    private int ID;
    private String Data;
    private Timestamp Date;

    public void setID(int id) {
        ID = id;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        Data = data;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp ts) {
        Date = ts;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return Data;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return Date;
    }
}
```

About `ds` or `Datasource`, a simple way to explain that is: It is simpler and safer way to do DB Authentication and Connection for Java. Added few comment about this in code above.

And what you said about [DS may be relevant]...hmm, sound like a black spot. I'll see if this is possible to be a cause.

Comment: You should tell us what JDBC driver you use

Comment: @RC. Those jdbc are copied from the other project, so I can only tell you their file name: `sqljdbc4.jar` and `sqljdbc41.jar`

Comment: @RajeevSreedharan I do posted `findData()` above. What else do you like to know?

Comment: I'm just a DBA (not a java expert by any means), but if it were me, I'd put some logging in the fetching section of your `findData()` method (specifically in the conditional after the `executeQuery()` call. I'd also be curious to know what your `MyData` class looks like. The first tells you whether that call is actually getting the data. The second might inform whether the data is getting persisted in those class properties or not.

Comment: Also, what is `ds` in `ds.getConnection()`? It may be relevant. I suspect not, but let's not rule anything out at the moment.